# Sort SQL Server column that contains number in the varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sorting

I've an SQL Server 2016 table that stores following data in a varchar like bellow:

```
1
1-1
1-1-1
1-2
1-1-1-20
1-1-1-5
1-1-2
1-1-1-25
1-15-2
1-1.5
```

It will sort asc as default like:

```
1
1-1
1-1.5
1-1-1
1-1-1-20
1-1-1-25
1-1-1-5
1-1-2
1-15-2
1-2
```

But I want to sort each number between '-' was sort as number like this

```
1
1-1
1-1.5
1-1-1
1-1-1-5
1-1-1-20
1-1-1-25
1-1-2
1-2
1-15-2
```

Comment: How many max separators can be in your numbers?

Comment: build your logic at the `order by` accordingly

Comment: @GauravS It was uncertainty, it may be 0 to 9 or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will helps

```
declare  @TableName table(Column1 varchar(10))

insert into @TableName values
('1'),
('1-1'),
('1-1-1'),
('1-2'),
('1-1-1-20'),
('1-1-1-5'),
('1-1-2'),
('1-1-1-25'),
('1-15-2'),
('1-1.5')

DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(50) = '-' 
;WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT column1,
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(column1, @delimiter , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML)  
        AS [Description XML]
    FROM  @TableName
)
SELECT column1

FROM CTE

Order by [Description XML].value('/M[1]', 'float'), [Description XML].value('/M[2]', 'float'), [Description XML].value('/M[3]', 'float'), [Description XML].value('/M[4]', 'float'),
[Description XML].value('/M[5]', 'float'), [Description XML].value('/M[6]', 'float'), [Description XML].value('/M[7]', 'float'), [Description XML].value('/M[8]', 'float'), [Description XML].value('/M[9]', 'float')
```

Comment: That was what I extremely wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Based on you example, Case statement into the Order By would help you:

```
SELECT column1 FROM@TableName
ORDER BY  CASE Column1
when '1' then 1
when '1-1' then 2
when '1-1.5' then 3
when '1-1-1' then 4
when '1-1-1-5' then 5
when '1-1-1-20' then 6
when '1-1-1-25' then 7
when '1-1-2' then 8
when '1-2' then 9
when '1-15-2' then 10
else column1 END
```

Comment: The data in question might just be for example... Answer has to be generic, I think.

Comment: @Raska Yes, this answer just for this example, and I want to has the generic sorting logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please find below answer

    **Create table test
(
 id varchar(250) 

)**

 - insert into test  values('1')

   insert into test  values('1-1')

   insert into test  values('1-1-25')

   insert into test  values('1-1-5')

   insert into test  values('1-1-10')

        SELECT id FROM test

    ORDER BY 

    CASE WHEN PatIndex('%[-]%',id) > 0

          THEN LEFT(id,PatIndex('%[-]%',id)-1)

          ELSE id END * 1

    ,CASE WHEN PatIndex('%[-]%',REVERSE(id)) > 0

          THEN RIGHT(id,PatIndex('%[-]%',REVERSE(id))-1)

          ELSE NULL END * 1
```